# How do I permanently disable chrome updates on my EC2 Virtual computers?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, group-policy

I currently have 5 EC2 Virtual Machines, each of which has a chrome browser installed and 40 browser profiles.

Chrome updates itself every few hours, even though I have tried several different options to get it to stop.

I have tried disabling the auto update feature using a group policy edit, then restarting the virtual machine. It seems to go without update for a short period of time (a few hours), then updates.

I have disabled Google Update Services as well as Gogle Chrome Elevation Service. None of this has worked.

I would like to prevent Google Chrome from updating indefinitely.